# Java/Selenium - The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect (java.io.IOException)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written a simple selenium script to capture screenshot and for some reason, this script is throwing the exception:

> java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

```
public class ScreenshotUtil {

    WebDriver driver;

    public ScreenshotUtil(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public String getScreenShot(String fileName) {
        SimpleDateFormat dFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyy HH-mm-ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        dFormat.format(date);
        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
        File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String path = "./Screenshots/" + fileName + "_" + date + ".png";
        File destination = new File(path);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

Comment: `dformat.format(date)` returns a `String` (i.e. `"12-10-2020 22-04-04"`) which you're not using, Your `path` string is having `date.toString()` (i.e. `"Mon Oct 12 22:04:04 GMT 2020"`) appended to it before `".png"`.

Comment: How do I fix this? Any suggestion?

Comment: `String path = "./Screenshots/" + fileName + "_" + dformat.format(date) + ".png";` . Your problem might be caused by the space in your final path, from your date format string (`"dd-MM-yyy HH-mm-ss"`), perhaps try replacing the space with an uderscore or hyphen (i.e. `"dd-MM-yyy_HH-mm-ss"`).

Comment: Great! it worked - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You use Unix-style paths on Windows.

Change your current path separator `/` to `File.separator` to achieve cross-platform execution for your code.

A quick fix for your code:

```java
String path = "." + File.separator + "Screenshots" + File.separator + fileName + "_" + date + ".png";
```

Comment: I implemented your fix but still no luck...still seeing the same exception java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect